# Phone_number data is not getting reflected in profile _page

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**FORMS.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone_number = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','phone_number' ,'password1', 'password2'] 

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone_number = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone_number']

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, UserProfileForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST) # -> it will create a new form with the data in it.
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for the {username}!, Please Login')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()  #-> if it is not post we create a blank form
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form  = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,
                                 request.FILES,
                                 instance=request.user.profile
                                 )
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ' Account Details has been Updated! ')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    

    context ={
                'u_form' : u_form,
                'p_form' : p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**PROFILE.HTML**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class = 'content-section'>
    <div class = 'media'>
        <img class = 'rounded-circle account-img' src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h2 class = 'account-heading'>{{user.username}}</h2>
            <p class = 'text-secondary'>{{user.email}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Update Profile</legend>
            {{ u_form|crispy }}
            {{ p_form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

i have stored all the data in database, and expecting to get the phone_number data in profile form, by default as i am getting email, username and profile_picture, why does this happens can anyone explain please, and even i haven't marked the phone_number field as required=true, still it is acting as required filed,

and any best courses or youtube channel to learn django and to make my projects

Comment: fields are required by default, you need to set blank=True in model or required=False in Form.